# Rename a struct member and all usage of it in a file

Tags: c, emacs, struct, ide, renaming

Can I using emacs or an IDE(MS/Mono/sun studio etc) do rename a struct member and all usage of it (I mean, with -> or . operators)  in a file? for example I have

```
struct foo { int a_1, int int b_2; //etc }
```

And I change struct to something like this:

```
struct foo { struct { int a_1, int b_2; } v; //etc }
```

And there's a lot of `f->a_1` or `f.a_1` and `f->b_2` or `f.b_2` in source code of `struct foo` or `struct foo*` type that now I need to replace to compiler find it in the `v` struct: `f.v->a_1` instead of. How could I do this?

Regexp is an ugly solution (that I could to do if the other solution is do it manually) but not possible because it need to match type of struct too. So, it need to be performed text editor/IDE that knows about C types. If you don't know how to do this with emacs but do with an IDE tell me please.

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but can't you just query-replace with Emacs, to replace `->a_1` by `.v->a_1` and `.a_1` by `.v.a_1`?  Sounds like a literal string replacement, no?

Comment: Maybe, this is helpful: `semantic-mode`, `Development->Navigate Tags->Find Tag References`. Search for your tag. There opens a `Symref` buffer. There you can rename the tag. `Symref->Expand all entries`, `Rename symbol in open hits`.

Comment: @Drew: The problem is there's others members of struct of different type with same name that will be replaced too. But isn't what I want but of a specific struct type

Comment: Then maybe correct your example, since it seems to be satisfied by what I suggested. Show an example that corresponds to what you really need; one that is not amenable to such a simple query-replace.

Comment: I think that my last statement say exactly what I'm looking for...

Comment: Somewhat off topic: wouldn't it be `f->a_1` to `f->v.a_1` instead of `f.v->a_1`?

Comment: @jpkotta: Yes. I will edit it

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with RTags's Emacs plugin:

https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags/

`rtags-rename-symbol`  (default binding: <kbd>C-x r R</kbd> )

Disclaimer:

I find it works **very** well, but I have had issues with macro renaming and heavy templated c++ code (these could already be fixed in the latest version).

It also can rename symbols across multiple files in one go (if you are using a project a la a compile_commands.json), so stash/save your changes before you test on your code - just in case.

Answer (score 0):

[coccinelle / spatch](https://coccinelle.gitlabpages.inria.fr/website/) does this.

I do not consider myself an expert in it, so if anyone has a more accurate patch example for this case, please share it. This simple patch already does the job:

```
@@
struct foo *ptr;
identifier x;
@@

- ptr->x
+ ptr->v.x

@@
struct foo val;
identifier x;
@@

- val.x
+ val.v.x
```

example on this input file `t.c`:

```
struct foo { int a_1, b_2; };
// struct foo { struct { int a_1, b_2; } v; };

void main(void) {
    struct foo f;
    struct foo *fp;

    f.a_1 = 1;
    f.b_2 = 2;

    fp->a_1 = 3;
    fp->b_2 = 4;
}
```

run spatch:

```
$ spatch --sp-file rename.cocci t.c -o tt.c
init_defs_builtins: /usr/bin/../lib/coccinelle/standard.h
HANDLING: t.c
diff = 
--- t.c
+++ /tmp/cocci-output-71364-cd13c6-t.c
@@ -5,9 +5,9 @@ void main(void) {
    struct foo f;
    struct foo *fp;
 
-   f.a_1 = 1;
-   f.b_2 = 2;
+   f.v.a_1 = 1;
+   f.v.b_2 = 2;
 
-   fp->a_1 = 3;
-   fp->b_2 = 4;
+   fp->v.a_1 = 3;
+   fp->v.b_2 = 4;
 }
```

Then edit tt.c to use the new struct definition and the source compiles.

Comment: FYI: The first line of your spatch at the top shows `@` but needs to be `@@` or `spatch` fails to parse it.

Comment: @KJ7LNW thank you, this obviously was a cut&paste mistake. edited.